# Kings on a chess board

Tags: combinatorics

It's a pretty straightforward problem to find the number of ways to place a king in every row and file so that they don't attack each other for an $n\times n$ grid. (https://oeis.org/A002464/internal)
However, what if you need two kings on every row and file (again, they can't attack each other). It's not hard to find the two permutations for the $8\times 8$ grid, but what about a $9\times9$ grid? How many ways are there to do that?

Comment: [Brute force for n=9,10.](https://tio.run/##nVTRboIwFH2Gr7hvwsQFupeNzH3F3gghVYqQ1JbUummM387agoCIkXkTCLTn3HPv4ZbyKHPO3qoqJRlgSpOS4jXZEiZ3DvNgvRdCPSeC/8ISfDe0bVCxoXyFKZRYyAJTBeM0WfO9ItX7RXbNVNTQbOhoWPpxCVHkx/ACDDIuIIGCgcBsQxzmxi2hy64JNf6eDut0jgWh6UWtXRVE7kVD15o6edDTXaBLkzpkLghJ8Ir/kISSTKoCmoRRX3gBQRxt8cGps6lXT5kFYZN9Dige1voFPhC6IxDFnZzCMC4Bs6MzVHbVatqzIjKpY/gE1Ku33xXqumrL8IC54RVax81CX1wUm3xS32jQN5re94P@TQmjBqAxAwaD1q84vti2hOB/HHSfc/tR5hOhqIGOYuv5zQTfPjiYcwjc0QxPuOI/4Yo/0ZXFdFcM1NaTzPQUR@8efHgQ@HFoWwZpZK32pzE0SA251QCNwVYpCiadbPadE0EAq@tkts/Q0czJwXBiZziY@4pjkb7O3Kr6Aw "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Comment: Is there a clean way to do it, or is the best way a computer program bash?

Comment: Not that I know of. The numbers for $n=8,9,10$ are not in OEIS.