# Non-attacking kings on an $n\times n$ board with the same number in each row and column

Tags: combinatorics, chessboard

Building on my previous question: [Kings on a chess board](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4027340/kings-on-a-chess-board).

What is the smallest square board that could have three non-attacking kings in every row and column. (Note: kings attack each other by being adjacent horizontally, vertically, or diagonally)

More generally, for each positive integer $t$, what is the smallest square board on which you can place several non-attacking kings so there at least $t$ kings in each row and column?

Comment: I feel like the answer is 16, but how would you prove it?

Comment: I'm not sure how that would help. You can put 1 king per row and column on a 4x4 board but not a 3x3 board. You can put 2 kings per row and column on an 8x8 board, but not a 7x7 board. How would I extend this to 3 kings per row and column?

Comment: Of course if there are exactly 3 kings in each row and each column the board is necessarily square.